# Does my Smartphone Listen to me for Ads?

Tags: google, privacy, microphone

I was talking to a friend about a tour to a location, the next day I'm getting ads about that travel plans. I asked a friend something about the best way to root an android device... the next day when I open youtube the very first suggestion for me to watch was how to root an android device!”

Is Google always listening on Android? Does Google keep a log of everything we say? And if so, what can we do about it?

Comment: If you are using "OK Google", it's been reported many times that Google stores voice snippets. You can turn that off and other invasive privacy features. https://clark.com/technology/google-recording-you-delete-files/

Comment: Related question https://android.stackexchange.com/q/188597/131553

Comment: Your question cannot be answered with certainty. None will tell you clearly what data they collect and how they use it for profiling. // I observed the same thing with Facebook app in past. The suggestions and ads were personalized based on the keywords I used in my conversation with friends and colleagues. Many of my friends also observed the same from time to time. I don't use Facebook, OK Google or other similar apps, particularly those which run background/foreground services. If using such apps is unavoidable (like Google Play Services), I restrict their permissions as much as possible.